# quotient of P.I.D by a prime power a P.I.D?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

If $R$ is a P.I.D. and $p\in R$ is prime, is it the case that $R/<p^k>$ will be a P.I.D for all k? If so how would one show this?

Comment: What are your thoughts ? Have you considered any simple cases, let's say $R = \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: aw thanks i feel a bit stupid.. because [p] will be a zero divisor when k>1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $k\ge 2$, then the quotient will have zero divisors and not even be an *integral* domain. (A PID needs to be an integral domain by definition).